# how to make Hashmap orderly?

Tags: java

can I get a Hashmap which key orderly except use LinkeHashmap?

```
        Map<String,String> myMapTmp = XXDao().getXXX();
        Map<String,String> myMap = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();

        List<String> keyList = new ArrayList<String>();
        Iterator<String> it =myMapTmp.keySet().iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            keyList.add(it.next());
        }
        Collections.sort(keyList);
        Iterator<String> it2 = keyList.iterator();
        while(it2.hasNext()){
            String key = it2.next();
            myMap.put(key, myMapTmp.get(key));
        }
```

Comment: You mean, get a `HashMap` to be in any sort of order, without using a `LinkedHashMap`?  No, you can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `TreeMap` with mappings of `HashMap`

```
Map<String,String> myMapTmp = XXDao().getXXX();
// TreeMap keeps all entries in sorted order
TreeMap<String, String> sortedMap = new TreeMap<>(myMapTmp);
Set<Entry<String, String>> mappings = sortedMap.entrySet(); 
System.out.println("HashMap after sorting by keys in ascending order "); 
for(Entry<String, String> mapping : mappings){ 
   System.out.println(mapping.getKey() + " ==> " + mapping.getValue()); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a treeMap from the existing map so the  treeMap  will have all the entries sorted.

```
TreeMap<Integer, String> treeMap = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
treeMap.putAll(myMapTmp);
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply use LinkedHashMap. it will give you desired result.

Comment: LinkedHashMap will always maintain the keyin insertion order only it won't order based on key

Comment: I know that already, but since question was not for key, it was related to provide capability like LinkedHashMap. please read question properly. Since LinkedHashMap provides Ordering based on insertion. and thats what is expected in question.